# Defining __add__ (and other magic methods) dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've heard that `a + b` expands to `a.__add__(b)`. However, it doesn't work like that in my code. Take this code:

```py
class TestAdd:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == '__add__':
            return (lambda y: self.a + y)
```

When I try `TestAdd(5).__add__(1)`, it returns 6 correctly. When I try `TestAdd(5) + 1`, it raises this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1c04c7082b89> in <module>
----> 1 TestAdd(5) + 1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'TestAdd' and 'int'
```

Why is this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you just define `__add__`? What are your constraints which require you to do this instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic methods aren't looked up on instances, but on classes. `TestAdd(5) + 1` is more precisely equivalent to `tmp = TestAdd(5); TestAdd.__add__(tmp, 1)`, and you haven't defined `TestAdd.__add__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `__getattr__` to dynamically return a magic method; this is documented in depth in [3.3.10 Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) in the manual.